# is there any way I could adjust line spacing of text in ubuntu?

Tags: text-editors, kde, ubuntu-16.04, cinnamon, ubuntu-unity

both kate and gedit have very annoying line spacing issue in ubuntu/kubuntu 16.04 (unity, cinnamon, KDE, I haven't test other DEs yet). The line spacing keep varying from line to line depending on what characters in that line. In kate the line spacing is too small. In gedit the line spacings vary too much. In Kubuntu14.04, we do not have this problem.
[image]

```
a¥￦╭∩╮(-_-)╭∩╮<{=·····
<{=·····<{=·····-_-b(￣(工)￣)
╭∩╮凸-_-凸<{=·····
<{=·····(￣(工)￣)
    {}
    {}
        <{=·····(￣(工)￣)
        aa{}
{}
{}╮(￣▽￣") 
{}
{}╭Σ( ￣д￣；)
{}
```

update2:
after introduction the kubuntu backports, it became better but still ugly, still hope to find a way to control the line spacing.

[image]

Comment: So you've noticed that the choice of desktop determines this?  Have you looked in the system configuration settings in each desktop to see what the default font is?

Comment: @fixer1234 thanks for tips. I actually found almost all DEs in ubuntu 16.04 have the exactly same issue not matter what font they are on.

Comment: In [Atom](https://atom.io/) you can set the line spacing in the config file: (%USERPROFILE%\.atom\config.cson):

`editor:
  fontFamily: "ubuntu mono"
  fontSize: 19
  lineHeight: 1.2`

Comment: By the way you might want to know https://askubuntu.com/ for questions regarding Ubuntu.

Comment: @MSC atom looks nice, hope it get into ubuntu soon. I still miss the sublime-text which has been dropped out after trusty.

Comment: I use Atom in Windows and Ubuntu. Check it out, it is there.

Answer (score 1):

If these text editors miss the Line-spacing opt, try the **CudaText** editor. To change line-spacing in it (one for all lines), open user.json config, and write option:

```
"spacing_y": 2,
```

or `-1` to make smaller.

Comment: thank you kind sir!